# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

> Error Message:- Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory
> 'libs'] on object of type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> Code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext {
    supportVersion='27.1.1'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eassycars.www.dlservices"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        configure(':app') {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:4.8.1'
            implementation fileTree (include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            implementation "com.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler :$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"
            implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.4'
            // utils
            implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
            annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
            implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
            implementation 'com.github.Commit451:bypasses:1.0.4'
            implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
            annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
            implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1'
            implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
        }}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I updated the "distributionUrl in my "gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties" file to match the current gradle version.

I also updated the classpath in my top level build.gradle file to match the gradle API level.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```

Re-synced and then it built OK.

Comment: if your android studio version is 3.6.1, update the classpath to -

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between version:

```
implementation "com.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler:$supportVersion"
```

Also, please move the dependencies block out of the android block:

```
android {
...
}
...
dependencies{
...
}
```

Comment: Gradle DSL method not found: 'configure()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'DLServices' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.1.3 and sync project</li><li>The project 'DLServices' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file</li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin</li>

Answer (score 0):

Because you have incorrect block in your build.gradle. Looks like you're mixing **top level** build.gradle and module build.gradle. Your **app** module build.gradle should be something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    ...
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      ...
    }
  }

  ..
}

dependencies {
  ...
}
```

please visit [Configure your build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/) for details.

Comment: No Its Not Working

Comment: Check your build.gradle, this is incorrect: `configure(':app') {
        dependencies {`